# How create deployement using helm3, that pulls image from docker hub?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have docker image in my repo, akshay123007/lists-pods. I have created helm chart
image:

```
 repository: akshay123007/lists-pods
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets: 
  - name: regcred 
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

when i install chart ,i get error as: Failed to pull image "akshay123007/lists-pods:1.16.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for akshay123007/lists-pods:1.16.0 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.

I have tried changing image:docker.io/akshay123007/lists-pods:latest, then it says errImagePull.I dont what is the issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the tag "1.16.0" exists in your Docker image?

Comment: no, the tag is latest @VasiliAngapov

Comment: please provide yaml of your deployment

Comment: by default it was taking chart version. so i removed {{.Values.tag...}}. able to pull image successfully, Thanks for noticing.@VasiliAngapov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget about the registry where it should take your image. It should be like this

```
image:  
    registry: YOUR_DOCKER_REGISTRY (EX: docker.io)  
    repository: akshay123007/lists-pods
```